# Super key not showing "Activities" if the keyboard layout is not English

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, 20.04, activities-overview

I use different keyboard layouts on my computer. The <kbd>Super</kbd> key works as expected with "English (with dead keys on Alt-Gr)" showing the Activities overview, but when switching to other layouts, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key has no effect. Combinations like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> work as expected on every layout.

I've used `xev` to check that the keystroke is detected, and the output of `xev` is the same for different keyboard layouts.

I've updated the official Ubuntu (GNOME) 18.04 to 20.04. The issue was not happening before the upgrade and I'd like to avoid "fresh reinstall" as a solution.

Comment: It does not seem to be a general problem. I took the exact same upgrade path yesterday. Switching between German and Japanese layouts leaves the Super key working just fine. Can't be of more help, have an upvote though :-)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The question you mention is indeed the same that mine. The other question is closed, and the issue seems to be a bug on Gnome. I think that it is worth to have a question (I do not really care if it is mine or the other one) referring the issue/question, so further readers can find that it is an identified bug. Once it is solved, the already proposed answer can be edited and accepted.

Comment: @Manuel: Actually I agree on what you are saying. For that reason I tried to prevent that the other question (which was first, a few more have been submitted afterwards) was closed. But they didn't listen... Anyway, it doesn't matter much, since the bug has been fixed upstream and will make it to focal soon.

Comment: @pomsky please see previous comments

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I upgraded 19.10 to 20.04 and my English International keyboard no longer toggles the activity menu. Other keystrokes like `Super+L` are still working, just not plain `Super`